# How to query exactly one particular layer with "Identify feature" tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, identify

Basic question: is there a way to unable attributes consulting for a given layer? I have several layers I need to visualize at the same time, but I would like to specify that I want to question one specific layer when I click the canvas using « Identify feature » option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order your layers so that the one you want to query is at the top, then
 select 'top down, stop at first' as shown in the `Mode` dropdown list

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that option! By selecting `Current layer` in the dropdown list, it also enables choosing exactly the layer to query.